# Magento catalog disappear after reindex

Tags: magento, catalog, reindex

One of my clients has tried to add a product attribute called 'Shipping Date' to products earlier today. He has created the attributed, and then assigned into default attributes set. After the he re-indexed everything to realised that category navigation menu has disappeared. He then deleted the added attribute and re-indexed again without any luck. I am now looking into it and I can't find anything wrong. All products are there as I can find those if I search for products. But I can't get the category navigation menus or go to individual products (before you ask, all products have been set up to show both in catalog and search).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look @ http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/02/when-reindexing-in-magento-fails-use-the-command-line/

Comment: @R.S Thanks mate. Just tried it , but it didn't work... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try clearing cache after?

Comment: Maybe you could try two things 1) backup and delete the indexes files located at magento/var/locks 2) deactivate the flat catalog if enabled and reindex your shop

Comment: @SylvainRayé I tried the first one but had no luck. I believe I had to re-index after I backed up deleted those indexes? And the flat catalog is not enabled. Here's the site if you would like to have a look: www.pooodle.co.uk

Comment: @R.S Yes I cleared cache after rebuilding indexes...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now with a current project I work on. I will let you know I resolve it. I feel that it could be a module conflict (in my case) or some trouble with attributes. The best solution is to analyze the sql collection query which can be done thanks to `$collection->load(true);`

Comment: Did you check your error log or try coping the site to a dev environment to make sure nothing change on the server itself? After doing a reindex do you get a error, success or nothing happen?

Comment: @R.S I've looked into a few error files and I'm not sure which one I should be looking at. Reindexing worked successfully, every time I tried it.

Comment: It seems the problem is something to do with the template. I enabled the default theme earlier and I got the categories back. But when I enabled the custom theme again, I lost those again...

Comment: This is the error message I get when enable display errors in index.php: 'Notice: Undefined index: isAjax  in xxx/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml on line 15
#0 xxx/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml(15): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 15, Array)'

Comment: Your error notice doesn't seem to have any influence with your problem. This error shows cart problem but no catalog problem. But you probably right about your template. Did you change anything in the layout of your template (into xml code of CMS pages or in layout xml files)?

Comment: @SylvainRayé According to my client, all he has done was, added an attribute, assigned it to Default, activated a static block and reindexed everything. When he realised that he cannot see the catalog items any more and also category menu disappeared, he has removed that attribute, disabled the static block and reindexed again. But the problem remained and that's when he called me. I reset pretty much everything without any luck. When I disable Ajax related items from that template, I get a different error message. I will copy it here as the next thing.

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 316: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: block line 237 and reference  in xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 444, Array)
#1 xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(444): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 
And few more lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is what I did. After I took Sylvain's advice about enabling the default theme, it was apparent that this was something to do with a corrupted XML file. Luckily I had a back up from a week ago, so I replaced all theme xml files with that back up. Flushed cache and now we are back in business. Thank you so much for all the tips guys. You all are making this world a bearable place to live :-)